# ¿Cómo crear un dataframe a partir de una lista de listas y una lista con python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Digamos que si tengo dos listas así:

```
lista1=[1,2,3]
lista2=[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h']
```

Necesito crear un dataframe a partir de estas dos listas, así:

```
| lista1       | lista2        |
| ------------ | ------------- |
| 1            | a             |
| 1            | b             |
| 1            | c             |
| 2            | d             |
| 2            | e             |
| 2            | f             |
| 3            | g             |
| 3            | h             |
```

pero no sé cómo hacerlo; mi actual código:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame((zip(lst1,lst2)), columns = ['Lista1','Lista2'])
```

crea esto:

```
| lista1       | lista2        |
| ------------ | ------------- |
| 1            | [a,b,c]       |
| 2            | [d,e,f]       |
| 3            | [g,h]         |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil de hacerlo sería utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) en combinación con [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) para volver a ajustar los índices del `dataframe`

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

lista1 = [1,2,3]
lista2 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h']]

df = pd.DataFrame((zip(lista1,lista2)), columns = ['Lista1','Lista2'])
df = df.explode('Lista2').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos

|  | Lista1 | Lista2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 1 | b |
| 2 | 1 | c |
| 3 | 2 | d |
| 4 | 2 | e |
| 5 | 2 | f |
| 6 | 3 | g |
| 7 | 3 | h |

Comment: :O no conocía esa función. Le agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Oh, okay, gracias

Comment: Buen día @Lobogrisx7, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).